Can't volume map nginx.conf to directory in docker container
I'm trying to mount an nginx.conf file to a volume in docker on a linux vps running ubuntu v23.04
This volume mapping works perfectly on macOS and Windows 11. ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro On mac I'm using docker v25.0.3. Why doesn't this work on ubuntu v23.04?
I tested everything on local windows, then mac machines, then I git cloned my repo into my VPS at /docker_projects/personal-site-2024/, built it, ran it and I get the following error:
ERROR: for personal-site-2024_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/docker_projects/personal-site-2024/nginx.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf": mount /docker_projects/personal-site-2024/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5001: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/docker_projects/personal-site-2024/nginx.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf": mount /docker_projects/personal-site-2024/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5001: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I have tried the following mapping /nginx_conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d after putting my .conf file into a dir called nginx_conf. I don't get an error when using this mapping but the .conf file does not appear in the conf.d dir inside the nginx container, so it's completely non-functional.
The mask for the .conf file is -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1009 Apr  9 14:49 nginx.conf

Snippet from docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
# This makes the dockerised containers publicly accessible so that
# runtime fetch requests made by the webserver (in browser) reach
# the containers sequestered in the docker network through forwarding
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - webserver
      - api_proxy_server
      - cms_server


I've tried the following:

naming the .conf file default.conf
putting the .conf into an nginx_conf and changed the mapping to /nginx_conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d


On the system where it doesn't work, can you verify that nginx.conf exists in the same directory as docker-compose.yml, and it is a regular file?  That sounds like the error if the source file doesn't exist, maybe because you're only copied the Compose file to the deployment system.

I’m 100% sure that the .conf file is there. I transferred it over via sftp and it shows over sftp and when I execute ls -a over ssh.

to be clear if you docker compose run --entrypoint /bin/sh nginx -c "cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf" it shows the wrong (default) contents?

if I use this mapping ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro the container won't run at all, if I use this mapping /nginx_conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d it will run, but the none of the files in the nginx_conf folder will be present in conf.d
